# Code readability: how to specify styling for CSS properties that accept multiple values

Tags: css, coding-style, readability

**Background:**

When using CSS to apply styling for elements, you can specify the amount of margin (for example) an element should have like so:

```
margin: 2px; // Good
```

This applies a `2px` margin on all sides of an element. You can also apply different margins on different sides of an element like so:

```
margin: 2px 4px; // Good
```

This applies `2px` margin on the top and bottom, and `4px` margin on the left and right sides. You can use this same pattern to specify the same margin on all sides:

```
margin: 2px 2px; // Bad
```

But this is bad because you're "repeating" the styling and making it unnecessarily complex. You could just use the first example above, which is easier to read and (should) be more consistent.

**Questions:**

*When is it okay to repeat yourself like in the third example, if ever?*

Also, what about cases like below?

```
// Option 1
margin: 2px 8px 2px 2px;

// Option 2
margin: 2px;
margin-right: 8px;
```

*Is one of the above options better? What pros and cons does each have, if any?*

I've been using the first option because setting property (`margin-right`) in the same selector seems like bad style. I find the second slightly easier to understand for me though, because it reads like "apply 2px everywhere except the right side, which is 8px" instead of "apply 2px top, 8px right, 2px bottom, 2px left".

Comment: I would think something like that would be up to personal preference.

Comment: I cannot say anything about performance, so i will merely post a comment. I also sometimes partly overwrite a rule in the next line - i don't see a reason not to. But now that i think of it, i kind of realize i usually did it out of laziness. `margin: 2px 2px;` of course makes no practical sense as long as there is `margin: 2px;` and it yields the same results (which is the case). Two equal values can only make sense when there is at least a third one. Otherwise one will suffice.

Comment: @JustinWood Thanks for the comment! I'm definitely okay with that if it's just personal preference. I'm just looking for a reason if there does exist one. A lot of things can be implemented different ways, but there may be a reason it's done a certain way specifically. I may not realize it because I lack experience (maybe one method is more error-prone down the line), but the reasoning's there and there's no way to know unless I ask. I'd rather ask "why" and get "no reason" than just do whatever everyone else is doing and miss out on a chance to learn. :)

Answer (score 1):

I feel this question really is subjective, and you'll likely get different answers from different people.  However, I do want to proffer that the "right" answer is [Sass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29) or another CSS generator.  There, you could produce code like

```
$myMarginPlain: 2px
$myMarginSpecial: 8px

margin: $myMarginPlain $myMarginSpecial $myMarginPlain $myMarginPlain
```

which gives you the best of both worlds; all margin rules are now in the same line, with no overwriting, but changing the value only requires a change in a single place.

As for raw CSS, I prefer the first option as well for the same reasons you stated (you have a full understanding of `margin` after reading a single line), but since both options are functionally equivalent, it's hard to argue forcefully for one over the other.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a personal preference like @JustinWood said, but there is some merit to being more "specific" with your CSS.

For me, I try to break up my CSS properties as much as possible to make them easier to target with JS/jQuery.

For example, it's easier and cross-browser compatible to get the right margin using something like:

`$('#id').css('margin-right')`.

And to be completely honest, I'm not even sure how to get a specific shorthand value of CSS using the `css()` method. I would have to reference computed styles, and that is way more difficult than simply making my CSS more granular.

According to the Jquery API, *"Retrieval of shorthand CSS properties (e.g., margin, background, border), although functional with some browsers, is not guaranteed."*

Source: http://api.jquery.com/css/#entry-longdesc